# Fastest way to retrieve a list of keys containing a specified value

Tags: php, arrays

What is the fastest/best way to create a function that retrieves a list of keys, that all contains a specific value in an array:

```
$array = ( 0 => 0,
           1 => 0,
           2 => 1,
           3 => 2,
           4 => 1 );

$keys= retrieve_keys_with_value( 1, $array );
var_dump($keys);
/* 
array(2) {
  [0] => int(2)
  [1] => int(4)
}
*/
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$keys = array_keys($array, 1);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

You may also want to pass the third parameter (strict checking). Default is `false`.

*Remember. It's PHP there is almost always a function for what you are doing* ;)

Comment: Haha silly of me. I looked through like all of the array functions, never knowing you could add an extra parameter to array_keys(). Thx.

Comment: Needed to wait 10 minutes to do that. Should be able now. (Nope, three more minutes).

Comment: +1 for "It's PHP" and the "Function for it". Yeah. PHP rocks! SO is great. Very good answer :)